# Remove a comma from a string with XQuery

Tags: xquery

I have an XQuery variable, `$RequestinteractionIds`, with a value like `'47575','65656',`

I would like to get rid of the last comma.

Please suggest a solution using XQuery (I am using Oracle's XQuery OSB).

Comment: What have you tried?  I've never heard of Xquery, yet I could still google 'Xquery OSB replace' and see the oracle documentation come up as the first result.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler regular expression for `replace()` that would do the job would be:

```
replace("'47575','65656',", "(.*),$", "$1")
```

However, not everyone likes regular expressions or understands them, so you may find it more understandable to use `tokenize` and then `string-join`:

```
string-join(tokenize("'47575','65656',", ","), ",")
```

Comment: Or slightly shorter: `replace("'47575','65656',", ",$", "")`

Comment: Slight typo in tokenize, you need to weed out empty strings: `string-join(tokenize("'47575','65656',", ",")[. != ''], ",")`

Comment: You can try it live at http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/I18whREHAeWEUm46m6SG3hCbrGY%3D

Answer (score 3):

Good old substring should work too:

```
let $RequestinteractionIds := "'47575','65656',"
return substring($RequestinteractionIds, 1, string-length($RequestinteractionIds) - 1)
```

HTH!

Comment: @grtjn- This is the best, easy to understand solution :)